# Why doesn't the C preprocessor ignore invalid directives in blocks it skips?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Consider the following code:

```
#if 0
   #foobar
#endif
```

In this case, the preprocessor doesn't complain that `#foobar` isn't a valid preprocessor directive. It just skips the block because of `#if 0` and the code compiles fine.

Now consider the following code:

```
#if 0
   #if 1
#endif
```

In this case, the preprocessor suddenly complains that there's a missing `#endif` directive. This is confusing me because it shows that even in the case of `#if 0` the preprocessor doesn't seem to completely ignore what is in the `#if 0` block. It seems that `#if` directives are still parsed and the preprocessor will even enforce their correctness, i.e. each `#if` needs to be matched by an `#endif`, even in blocks that are skipped.

Previously, I was of the impression that encapsulating a block using `#if 0` / `#endif` was equivalent to commenting it using `/*` and `*/`. But apparently that is not the case.

Hence my questions:

1. What is the rationale behind this design? Why does the preprocessor enforce correctly matched `#if` directives even in blocks that the preprocessor is explicitly told to skip by using certain directives like `#if 0`?
2. Which directives *exactly* are handled in `#if 0` blocks? As shown in the example above, the preprocessor doesn't complain about invalid preprocessor directives like `#foobar` but it does complain about unmatched `#if` directives. So which preprocessor directives are actually handled in `#if 0` blocks? Only `#if` / `#ifdef` / `#elif` / `#else` / `#endif` or are there more directives that are handled in `#if 0` blocks?

Comment: Because the preprocessor does not know *which* `#if` is missing the `#endif`. Indentation does not tell it! In the second example, if you indented the `#endif` would the error message surprise you?

Comment: The preprocessor *has* to look at `#if`/`#endif` directives even inside a non-taken branch, otherwise nested `#if` couldn't possibly work.

Comment: D'oh, right, makes sense of course. It's very obvious why it has to be like that. Well, I guess let's blame it on Christmas :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only directives that could change the control flow are processed. The rest, like `#foobar` are ignored<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion 6)
Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group
that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines
the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the
directives’ preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the
group